# How can I allow multiple owners while enabeling mutation of value?

Tags: multithreading, rust, neural-network, smart-pointers

I have an ***Enum***, called ***NodeType*** which allows the values of ***Network(Network)*** or ***Mesh(Mesh)***. Both Network and Mesh are structs of ***unknown size***. A Network Instance contains a 2D Vector of Node Structs, which contain a NodeType Enum, which allows for Networks to contain other Networks or Mesh structs. Meshes do some arbitrary function.

Consider the following ***Network*** which has a NodeType vector of size ***1 x 3***. with the contents being: ***[Mesh, Network0, Network1]***. The ***first*** Element (Mesh), does something and is of no concern. The ***Second*** Element Network0 is created, and is assigned a NodeType(Mesh) on instantiation. As with the prior Network containing a Mesh, it is of no concern.

The ***Third*** Element Network1 is created the same way as Network0, with a NodeType(Mesh) defined on creation. However, we now want to append a new value to Network1's NodeType Vector. My issue is I am having trouble Assigning a value to a Struct that is Recursive and not the "Root" of the recursion loop. It is possible that a child Network May be referenced in more than one Parent Networks at any given time. I cannot perform a deep copy of these NodeType as it can potentially be (infinitely) large.

The Issue as I see it is a Node contains an Arc<RwLock>. But these are needed because Arc allows for many Networks to reference the same Struct instance, and RwLock allows management when threading.

Here are the Three structs used, as well as the main that instantiates the above scenario:

Node

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub(crate) struct Node {
    guid: Uuid,
    node: Arc<RwLock<NodeType>>,
}

impl Node {
    pub(crate) fn new(subnet: NodeType) -> Node {
        Node {
            guid: Uuid::new_v4(),
            node: Arc::new(RwLock::new(subnet))
        }
    }

    pub(crate) fn node(self) -> Arc<RwLock<NodeType>> {
        self.node.clone()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub(crate) enum NodeType {
    Network(Network),
    Mesh(Mesh),
}
```

Network

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub(crate) struct Network {
    guid: Uuid,
    pub(crate) subnet: Vec<Vec<Node>>,
}

impl Network {
    pub(crate) fn new(subnet: NodeType) -> Network {
        Network {
            guid: Uuid::new_v4(),
            subnet: vec![vec![Node::new(subnet)]],
        }
    }
}
```

Mesh

```
#[derive(Debug, )]
pub(crate) struct Mesh {
    guid: Uuid,
}

impl Mesh {
    pub(crate) fn new() -> Mesh {
        Mesh {
            guid: Uuid::new_v4(),
        }
    }
}
```

Main

```
    //Creates A NodeType(Mesh)
    let a = NodeType::Mesh(Mesh::new());
    //Assigns the NodeType(Mesh) as the Second Element
    let mut agent0 = Network::new(a);

    //Creates a NodeType(Network) that Contains a Single Mesh
    let b = NodeType::Network(Network::new(NodeType::Mesh(Mesh::new())));
    //Assigns A NodeType(Network) that Contains a NodeType(Mesh) as the first element.
    agent0.subnet[0].push(Node::new(b));

    //Creates a NodeType(Network), Containing A NodeType(Mesh)
    let c = NodeType::Network(Network::new(NodeType::Mesh(Mesh::new())));
    //Assigns A NodeType(Network) that Contains a NodeType(Mesh) as the third element.
    agent0.subnet[0].push(Node::new(c));

    //An Attempt to append an additional Mesh to the Third Element's NodeType Vector. (Not Currently Working)
    let value = (*agent0.subnet[0][2].node()).get_mut();
    if let NodeType::Network(mut content) = value {
        // let d = NodeType::Mesh(Mesh::new());
        // content.subnet[0].push(Arc::new(RwLock::new(NodeType::Mesh(Mesh::new()))))
    }
```

The Error Received is:

```
let i = (*agent0.subnet[0][2].node()).get_mut();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<async_std::sync::RwLock<NodeType>>`
```

I hope I was clear with my question, I decided risking over-explaining versus the alternative.

Comment: Reproducing your code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48723ede45c0b77a45bb97b30f996c17), it appears you just have simple type-mismatch errors (from not locking the `RwLock` for example) and not a problem with the overall design. If this is the only issue in question, please include the errors so that people can address them directly.

Comment: I will make the proper revisions. Done, I have also broken out the broken code a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you have an `Arc<RwLock<NodeType>>` but you're trying to `get_mut()` when you only have a non-mutable reference.  As [the documentation for `RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) says,

```rust
use std::sync::RwLock;

let lock = RwLock::new(5);

// many reader locks can be held at once
{
    let r1 = lock.read().unwrap();
    let r2 = lock.read().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(*r1, 5);
    assert_eq!(*r2, 5);
} // read locks are dropped at this point

// only one write lock may be held, however
{
    let mut w = lock.write().unwrap();
    *w += 1;
    assert_eq!(*w, 6);
} // write lock is dropped here
```

So what your code is missing is that the `Arc` only gives you a *non-mutable* reference to your `RwLock` which means you need to call `write` on it, and then `unrwap()` because of the possible results, as per the example above to get your mutable reference to the inner `NodeType`.

Edit:  I think this is what you want in your final section.  Not 100% sure though, as it doesn't clone your `Arc` but I think this is what you were *trying* to do:

```rust
    //An Attempt to append an additional Mesh to the Third Element's NodeType Vector.
    let mynode = &(agent0.subnet[0][2]);
    let mut locker = mynode.node.write().unwrap();
    if let NodeType::Network(content) = &mut *locker {
        let my_mesh_nodetype = NodeType::Mesh(Mesh::new());
        let my_fresh_node = Node::new(my_mesh_nodetype);
        content.subnet[0].push(my_fresh_node);
    }
```

Based on your comment in the code, I think this is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this prompts another error that "move occurs because value has type `Node`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait". This is after attempting to extract the value with: *agent0.subnet[0][2].node().write().unwrap(); I do not want to implement the copy trait because I imagine copying a recursive system of structs would be expensive.

Comment: Your `if let` may need to change too so that you are taking references as you go, and not just the underlying type.  Regardless, the `write` call is what you need, since even the example shows that you have a "pointer/reference" of a sort, and you have to take into account that you don't have `mut` references coming out of the `Arc`

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I must admit, I'm not too sure how to do an advanced match like that - but today I'll learn.

Comment: You are very welcome.  It bugged me that it wasn't complete, so spent the time on it.  I hope it helps.  I just hope a rust Guru comes along and fixes my code to compact it, as I think there's a way to be more concise, like with `deref_mut` or something.  Not counting the multi-line exploding of declarations, as that doesn't really matter, since it will be compiled away of course.